# API Store - Error Unable to execute Application Creation Workflow

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am working with wso2idm and wso2am. I am getting the following issue while creating application in wso2 store.

version and servers:

- mysql-5
- wso2is5.5.0
- wso2am2.5.0

  [2018-08-03 19:48:36,043] ERROR - TenantWorkflowConfigHolder Error loading Resource from path/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml
      org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
          at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
          at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
          at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
      [2018-08-03 19:48:36,068] ERROR - WorkflowExecutorFactory Error occurred while creating workflow configurations for tenant abc.com
      org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error loading Resource from path/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml
          at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.handleException(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:297)
          at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.load(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:162)
          at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowConfigurations(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:64)
          at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowExecutor ... 80 more

  [2018-08-03 19:48:36,079] ERROR - WorkflowExecutorFactory Error while creating WorkFlowDTO for AM_APPLICATION_CREATION
  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while creating workflow configurations for tenant abc.com
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.handleException(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:80)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowConfigurations(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:68)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowExecutor(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:86)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getWorkflowExecutor(APIConsumerImpl.java:3829)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.addApplication(APIConsumerImpl.java:2618)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.addApplication(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:85)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_addApplication(CacheBackedRegistry.java:225)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:198)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.load(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:78)
      ... 80 more

  [2018-08-03 19:48:36,148] ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Unable to execute Application Creation Workflow
  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error while creating WorkFlowDTO for AM_APPLICATION_CREATION
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.handleException(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:80)
  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while creating workflow configurations for tenant abc.com
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.handleException(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:80)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowConfigurations(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:68)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowExecutor(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:86)
      ... 78 more
  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error loading Resource from path/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.handleException(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:297)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.load(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:162)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowConfigurations(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:64)
      ... 79 more
  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:532)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getGhostResourceFromCache(CacheBackedRegistry.java:225)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:198)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.load(TenantWorkflowConfigHolder.java:78)
      ... 80 more

  [2018-08-03 19:48:36,161] ERROR - UserAwareAPIConsumer Unable to execute Application Creation Workflow
  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error while creating WorkFlowDTO for AM_APPLICATION_CREATION
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.handleException(WorkflowExecutorFactory.java:80)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowExecutorFactory.getWorkflowExecutor[2018-08-03 19:48:36,173] ERROR - application-add:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unable to execute Application Creation Workflow
  [2018-08-03 19:57:37,081]  INFO - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Running DB sync task.

Comment: Did you follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Adding+an+Application+Creation+Workflow to add application creation workflow